# Why i am getting Nan

Tags: javascript, nan

Trying to calculate BMI using the following code:

```
var mark = {
  fullName: 'John Cartor',
     Weight : 90,
     height : 1.59,
     calcBMI: function(){
        this.bmi= this.weight / (this.height* this.height);
       return this.bmi;
     }
};

john.calcBMI();
mark.calcBMI();

console.log(john, mark);
```

But I'm getting `Not a number` error.

Comment: You have a capital letter on your Weight property and are using a lowercase weight property in your calcBMI function - that makes it: undefined / 1.59 * undefined (Nan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what youre trying to achieve but you can try this:

```js
var mark = {
    fullName: 'John Cartor',
    weight : 90,
    height : 1.59,
    calcBMI: function(){
       this.bmi= this.weight / (this.height* this.height);
       return this.bmi;
    }
};

console.log(mark.calcBMI());
```

Property `Weight` should be `weight` and then you can call the method `calcBMI()`.

I'm showing you this approach as you've hard coded all the values. So, in this case it is pretty straight forward.